# Issues running requests to API using request library + nodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest, node-modules

I'm trying to run a request to an API using NodeJS and the request library.

```
var creds = {
    json: {
        email : "user",
        pass : "pw"
    }
}

var urlPost = "https://api.domain.rocks/auth.php"
request({
        url : urlPost,
        method : 'POST',
        json : true,
        body : creds
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(response.body)
    }
)
```

I get an error indicating that the parameters in the `creds` `json` object aren't sent correctly ("bad email"). I've tried all weird combinations of url encoding, query string package ...

I tested in Python, a language I'm more familiar with, and it works there using Python 2.7 and the request library. This gives me the authentication token which is what I need.

```
payload = {"email" : "email", "pass" : "pw"}
r = requests.post('https://api.domain.rocks/auth.php', data=payload)
rparsed = json.loads(r.text)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not to use `request.post()` ?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Isn't that equivalent to expressing the options in the request like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your python example you send payload `{"email" : "email", "pass" : "pw"}`

But in your JS code your payload is:

```
{
    "json": {
        "email" : "user",
        "pass" : "pw"
    }
}
```

Remove this `json` from your `creds` object.

```
var creds = {
    email : "user",
    pass : "pw"
}
```